# ios take screenshot of view and attach it to mail

Tags: ios, screenshot, attachment, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm working on an app and I would like to send, when I press a button, 2 screenshots of 2 views, attached it to an e-mail.

The two view controllers are called `secondViewController` and `commenViewController`

Currently I'm using this code:

```
- (void)buttonPress:(id)sender {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

    if ( [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] ) {
        MFMailComposeViewController * mailComposer = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        mailComposer.delegate = self;
        [mailComposer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"attachment.jpg"];

        /* Configure other settings */

        [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Which works fine for my first view, but I don't know how to take, in that action, a screenshot of my `commenViewController` and attach it to the mail as well...

Comment: When does an instance of the other view controller exist? Take an image of it at that time and save it?

Answer (score 0):

Wain has the right idea.  Before you segue or navigate into your "`secondViewController`", you should create a screenshot of your "`commenViewController`" and then save it in a file where you can pick it up in your "`secondViewController`" "`buttonPress`" method.

You can create that screenshot before you close or segue or pop the view in the navigation controller to leave "`commenViewController`".